# I have raid volume with 6 4TB drives, how do I back up this data

Tags: backup, raid

I see all over that raid is not a backup, i get that and everything. But i still have a raid for redundancy, but what should i do to backup this 16TB+ amount of data?

Comment: Not an answer, but you do the backup regardless of RAID or not. There isn't anything special to RAID that is relevant for a backup.

Comment: @GiantTree, doesn't that depend on the desired type of backup (e.g., files vs. clone)?

Comment: Is any of this duplicate data perhaps? What type of data you working with here exactly? Is it video/audio, pictures, text data, DB backup data, system image data, or what? Have you looked into compressing and deduplication technologies lately? There are many options but in the event the server your RAID is on catches on fire and you do have the data you need backed up elsewhere offsite, what are your requirements? Do you need to be back up in 5 minutes, 48 hours, or what? Backing up your data alone is not enough, you need to be able to restore it understand the procedure, and have a plan.

Comment: @fixer1234 the system will probably recognize the RAID as a single volume/block device. This means that it doesn't matter how the backup is done, as long as the RAID volume is deterministic, i.e. writing to one block will always occupy the same blocks on the volume.

Comment: If you've got a good enough internet connection you can backup off-site with backblaze (or a million [other systems](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-cloud-backup,review-2678.html)) - backblaze and others have a way to mail in a seed drive, so you can backup initially to local drive(s) and then mail, then do backups via internet for deltas. Depends what sort of data it is in part. Something like Amazon Glacier with Duplicati might be a good fit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tapes and/or, or back up to a similar off-site system if you are using zfs (snapshot replication).  Alternatively you might be able to do this with rsync/rsnapshot - possibly only backing up some directories if you have a combination of valuable files and downloaded data which can be redownloaded.

You might  be able to provide reciprocal services to a peer.

(For a better answer provide more details, like number of users, OS, budget, risk tolerance, home/business, your threat prifile, how often data changes, if you need roll back etc).

Answer (score 0):

For that amount of data, go with a [Blu Ray writeable drive](https://www.newegg.com/Blu-Ray-Burners/SubCategory/ID-600) and media.

Comment: How much data do you get on one disc , then how many discs and then how long to write 1 disc : so the total time is ? It will be like painting the Eiffel tower, once finished -all the data will have changed do start again...

Comment: they range from 25 to 100GB.  Speed is going to depend on a variety of factors.

Comment: So 16TB divided by 100GB ......